# UrlFetchApp returns no data from Wikidata SPARQL service

Tags: google-apps-script, wikidata-query-service

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script contained in a sheet to return XML from the Wikidata web service for SPARQL queries. I have a simple working SPARQL query and am using the URL-escaped https string, per the instructions in the [Wikidata user guide](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#SPARQL_endpoint).

Per the code below, I've tried UrlFetchApp.Fetch() both with and without the options parameter, but I always get an empty response. When I test the "simpleQry" url in my browser, it returns the correct xml file. I don't use web services very often, so I may be missing something obvious. Any help is greatly appreciated!

First I set the fetch options with JSON

```
 //set http header values w/json
var headr = {
    'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+xml'
};

//set options values w/json
var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'header': headr
};
```

Then I submit the request:

```
simpleQry = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=select%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FemployerLabel%20%3FworksLabel%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fperson%20%7Bwd%3AQ112129152%7D%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP108%20%3Femployer%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP800%20%3Fworks%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20'%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen'.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D";

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(simpleQry, options);
var dataAllxml = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText());
```

Process the results. This where the error gets uncovered. Length of content = 0.

```
var rows = [], data;

for (i = 0; i < dataAllxml.length; i++) {
    data = dataAllxml[i];
    rows.push([data.personLabel, data.employerLabel, data.worksLabel]); //
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- `XmlService.parse(response.getContentText())` returns XML Object. By this, `dataAllxml.length` becomes `undefined`. By this, the for loop is not run. I think that this is the reason for your issue of `Process the results. This where the error gets uncovered. Length of content = 0.`.

When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var headr = {
    'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+xml'
  };
  var options = {
    'method': 'get',
    'header': headr
  };
  var simpleQry = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=select%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3FemployerLabel%20%3FworksLabel%0Awhere%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fperson%20%7Bwd%3AQ112129152%7D%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP108%20%3Femployer%20.%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP800%20%3Fworks%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20'%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen'.%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(simpleQry, options);
  var dataAllxml = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText());

  // I modified below script.
  var root = dataAllxml.getRootElement();
  var ns = root.getNamespace();
  var rows = root.getChild("results", ns).getChildren().map(e => e.getChildren().map(f => f.getValue().trim()));
  console.log(rows);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this modified script is run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  ["Ramona L. Pérez","San Diego State University","Good and bad death: exploring the perspectives of older Mexican Americans."],
  ["Ramona L. Pérez","San Diego State University","Diabetes Cultural Beliefs and Traditional Medicine Use Among Health Center Patients in Oaxaca, Mexico."],
  ["Ramona L. Pérez","San Diego State University","Exposure to smoking in soap operas and movies: smoking cessation and attempts to quit."]
]
```

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)